# Changed behavior of _.flatten function in lodash v3?

Tags: lodash

This line of code has worked for a couple of months in production:

```
_.chain(data.Groups).flatten('Filters').pluck('Name').value();
```

So i have a list of Groups, each group has a collection of filters and those filters have a name property. I want a flat list of all names. I am 100% sure this code worked as intended, because it has been in production for months, in a tool that is very intensively used.

Last week, we noticed our lodash version was kinda outdated, so we updated from:

```
"lodash": "~2.4.1",
```

to:

```
"lodash": "~3.9.3",
```

Suddenly, the line mentioned above now returns undefined (discovered in production, unfortunately). I am a bit shocked that the behavior of such a method changes over versions. Apparently, its because the signatue of the flatten method simply changed. Ok, its a new major version, but i would still expect backwards compatibility ...

How can i achieve what i want in version 3 of lodash?

Comment: Major changes are the reason to make a new major version…

Comment: Can you provide the `data` structure that isn't working with the above code?